# Change Font Awesome Icon on next i tag

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I have an accordion, which in turn has a couple of inner accordions. The basic structure is like so

```html
<div class="accordion" id="accordion1">
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseTwo" id="accordianHeader">
                Main Title <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                <div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
                    <div class="accordion-group mtb-10">
                        <div class="accordion-heading">
                            <a class="accordion-toggle font-weight-bold" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseInnerOne">
                                Inner Title One <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapseInnerOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">
                            <div class="accordion-inner">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="accordion-group mtb-10">
                        <div class="accordion-heading">
                            <a class="accordion-toggle font-weight-bold" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseInnerTwo">
                                Inner Title Two <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapseInnerTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
                            <div class="accordion-inner">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, each `accordion-heading` has a font awesome `fa-chevron-right`.  When this is expanded, I want to change it to `fa-chevron-down`

At first, I tried

```js
$('.accordion').on('show.bs.collapse hide.bs.collapse', function (e) {
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-chevron-right fa-chevron-down');
});
```

But this seems to change all of them at the same time, not just the collapsed section.

I have also tried with closest and next, but this does not seem to do anything.

How can I get it changing the correct image?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind adding a click event instead of the show/ hide event, you can try doing like so:

```
$('#accordianHeader').click(function(){
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-chevron-right fa-chevron-down');
});
```

Checkout this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/divekarvinit/zvudmhny/) please.

**Updated:**

Another way (possibly, your preferred way):

```
$('.accordion').on('show.bs.collapse hide.bs.collapse', function (e) {
    $(this).find('i').first().toggleClass('fa-chevron-right fa-chevron-down');
});
```

Comment: The only issue with that is that I would need to do one of these for each header.  I wanted to use a class to avoid repeating code

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check the same.

Answer (score 0):

No need for `<i></i>` elements nor nasty jQuery, you can do this in pure CSS:

```css3
.accordion-toggle:not([aria-expanded]):after,
.accordion-toggle[aria-expanded="false"]:after {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: '\f054';
}
.accordion-toggle[aria-expanded="true"]:after {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: '\f053';
}
```

demo with the markup above except the `<i>` tags -> **http://jsfiddle.net/1drLbqpz/**

For a list of FontAwesome codes -> **https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet**